How to obtain JedisPooled in Spring Boot
I'm using Spring Boot 3.2.3 and spring-boot-starter-data-redis where I excluded lettuce and using jedis instead.
Is there any "spring-boot" way of obtaining JedisPooled object (instead of just creating it manually)? Creation of that object is already done in JedisConnectionFactory.
